# Remapping textures?

Tags: texture-baking

I was trying to bake the emit texture from the top image down to the bottom one. As you can see, they are different meshes entirely, and the bake gave subpar results. From what I can tell, the entire mesh needs to be above the bottom one, but I do not think I can do that without warping the results significantly, especially because the head on top is two seperate meshes, the ears and the head. The clay for just the head is similar to the clay on the bottom, just that the ears are seperate and symmetrical. Is there a way to do this easily without having to hand paint on the new mesh?
[image]
Here is the projected results, as you can see it looks blotted and is missing textures.

[image]

[image]
here is the file

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of your file, pre-bake, packing any images at sensible resolution. on https://blend-exchange.com/ ? It might be better to transfer UV coordinates, using the _Data Transfer_  modifier, but would want to check before answering.

Comment: Just added the file via blend-exchange, it has the bake result called "crouch" and the details from the head is called "head.png.002"

Comment: Instead of baking the texture across, I textured both heads with the same image, and attempted a transfer of the UV Map, using Data Transfer. Still a bit tatty, though see [here](https://imgur.com/a/rH0vPgv)

Comment: When I unwrap it (again) and bake it with the *Image Texture* node not being connected during baking, I get a similar result to Robin Betts. I've also adjusted the baking settings *Extrusion* to 0.04 and *Max Ray Distance* to 0 (=unlimited). It's mainly the UV map that causes problems. The tips of the ears have a very tiny UV space. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlZub.jpg) You need to add more seams to unwrap them properly. The legs suffer from the same problem while the tails look good.

Comment: There is also a loss of detail because the source objects (ears+head) have a 4k image texture, while the complete fox model (3 large tails, body, legs, head, and ears) uses a 2k image texture that is only 1/4 the size of the source image texture (area wise). If you are going to texture only the head you can enlarge the UV islands and shrink those of the body. Or consider UDIMs.

Comment: @Blunder I see, it had something to do with the extrusion, I didnt realize I had touched that setting, that explains some of the results I was getting. As for the UVs, I had 2 other foxes squeezed in the same UV, with a much larger resolution, but I did a rushed job just because I wanted to see the results. Now that I know it works, I can do a better job cutting up the mesh for the UVs.

Comment: @RobinBetts I did not know that UV transfer could work like that, I will definitely try that out. I could scale the image down to fit the rest of the body.